# Is it possible to have a symmetric and transitive relation on $\mathbb Z$ that isn't reflexive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I was wondering this the other day and I have been trying to come up with an example for a bit but can't produce one. If there is a proof that such a thing couldn't exist I would be interested in seeing it. Seeing an example of such a set would also be cool as well. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

The empty relation - nothing relates to anything else - is symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive.

Comment: In fact, this is essentially the only example: if $R$ is symmetric and transitive, then let $D=\{x: \exists y(xRy)\}$ be the set of elements which are $R$-related to anything at all; $R$ is reflexive if and only if $D$ is the whole domain of $R$. In particular, this means that, if $R$ is not reflexive, then there is some subset $S$ of the domain such that $R$, restricted to $S$, is the empty relation.

Answer (score -2):

Well it is simple that is must be reflexive.Let R be relation in Z such that it is both symmetric and transitive.

Let xRy and yRx,but then by transitivity it must hold that xRx.

Thus such relation can not exist.

Comment: In $\Bbb Z$ like elsewhere

Comment: There could be elements that are not related to any elements.

Comment: True,but then they would not belong to domain of the relation.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop It would still be a relation though. -1

Comment: If x is not related to anything then it does not belong to relation.It is absurdly obvious.I do not see a reason for -1 but ok

Comment: You can have a set though which is vacuously transitive. For example

Comment: But then same set is also vacously symmetric and thus also vacoulsy reflexive.

Comment: A relation on $X$ is just a subset of $X\times X$. There are no requirements for any element of $X$ to actually be related to anything. If every element is related to some other element, then--yes--symmetry and transitivity implies reflexivity.

Comment: Just because $\forall y(\neg xRy)$ does not mean that $x$ is not in the domain of $R$. -1.